# gcc objdump assembly debugging

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gdb, disassembly

I'm trying to change C code to assembly code.

At first, i used gcc and objdump function to extract assembly code from c code.

The C code was just simple printf code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("this\n");
    return 0;
}


gcc -c -S -O0 test.c
objdump -dS test.o > test.txt

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
   e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  13:   5d                      pop    %rbp 
  14:   c3                      retq
```

in this assembly code, 
i was curious why callq instructions destination is e

so i run this code in gdb using

disas main

```
    (gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400526 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400527 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040052a <+4>: mov    $0x4005c4,%edi
   0x000000000040052f <+9>: callq  0x400400 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400534 <+14>: mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000400539 <+19>: pop    %rbp
   0x000000000040053a <+20>: retq
```

in this code, i assumed that 0x400400 is the address of printf function.

Why does objdump and gdb's assembly code show different result?

How can i make objdump result shows the right callq destination?

Comment: Because the code has not been *linked*, the destination address for the call is just `00 00 00 00`. The linker will patch this when you link your executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the `objdump` command you are not disassembling the final executable, you are disassembling the object file produced by the compiler (`test.o`). I performed similar steps (using your code) to you (compiling and running `objdump` and `dissas` in GDB) except I performed the `objdump` on the linked executable *not* on the object file (this means I did not compile with the `-c` flag). The outputs are below:

```
objdump -dS a.out:
1140:       55                      push   %rbp
1141:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1144:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
1148:       48 8d 3d b5 0e 00 00    lea    0xeb5(%rip),%rdi        # 2004 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
114f:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
1156:       b0 00                   mov    $0x0,%al
1158:       e8 d3 fe ff ff          callq  1030 <printf@plt>
115d:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
115f:       89 45 f8                mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
1162:       89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
1164:       48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
1168:       5d                      pop    %rbp
1169:       c3                      retq   
116a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

GDB:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001140 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000001141 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001144 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000001148 <+8>:     lea    0xeb5(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2004
   0x000000000000114f <+15>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001156 <+22>:    mov    $0x0,%al
   0x0000000000001158 <+24>:    callq  0x1030 <printf@plt>
   0x000000000000115d <+29>:    xor    %ecx,%ecx
   0x000000000000115f <+31>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001162 <+34>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000001164 <+36>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000001168 <+40>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000001169 <+41>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

As you can see, the two disassemblies are the same, except for some minor syntax differences (e.g. GDB prefixes it's addresses with `0x`).

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing with `objdump` by default is relocations.

Running `objdump` with the `-r` flag lets you see these. e.g.

```
objdump -Sr foo.o

foo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
            5: R_X86_64_32  .rodata
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
            a: R_X86_64_PC32    puts-0x4
   e:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  13:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  14:   c3                      retq
```

Shows us that the call will use a PC relative address, pointing to `puts`